# Why does one of my pages not have the option to edit the link?

Tags: permalinks, urls

a colleague of mine broke the ACF functionality of one of our pages by editing it in Elementor, so I recreated it. I should clarify that I am not the admin of the site, just a semi-technically savvy end-user. So, I go to make the broken page inactive/draft, but I noticed that there is no option to change the URL. Most other pages have the option, but this one seems to be an outlier. I have tried doing things like changing the visibility and status of the page, as well as looking in files like wp-config for some kind of definition for the page. Why am I unable to make edits to the URL/link for a specific page like this? Do I need admin access? Would trashing the page open up that URL?

Comment: If you deleted the page you would also need to delete it from the trash and then the URL should be available.

Answer (score 0):

go to the interface and create a role kind of viewer and with any edition privilegies. and add capabilities 
https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/